# Are AdSense earnings capped based on the number of pages on your site?

Tags: google-adsense

So I wasn't quite sure how to word the question, so feel free to edit...

We have several sites that have been earning consistent AdSense revenue.  In an attempt to gain more revenue, we placed a pass-through page between search result links and their pages (external).

While the revenue went up for those pass-through clicks (obviously), it seems that the % of clicks has gone down on all the other ads.  CPC's went down a bit, while page views remained consistent.

We tested some clicks, and noticed that they were not registering.

So I'm curious to know if anyone else has experienced this.

Is there some ratio of how much you can make with AdSense vs the # of pages on your site?

Comment: Is this right:  you have search on your site.  When somebody clicks on one of the results of that search to go to an external site, you implemented an interstitial that shows adsense?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Ads are served on the results page.  We then added a hyperstitial.  The user is not locked there without clicking, and if no action is performed, the user is still presented with their expected page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdSense revenue is not capped by the number of pages on your site.   I have seen a number of reports of webmasters making layout changes that dramatically increase the amount of money that they make from AdSense.

I think that it is more likely that you are violating the AdSense policies.  Clicks are not counted for this reason and your revenue has not gone up because of this.   Specifically, here are two AdSense policies which you may be violating based on the description in your question:

### Ads are not allowed to be placed on <s>site search results or other</s> dynamic content.

[Ads *are* allowed on site search results](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354757?hl=en), but not on other dynamic content. You can also use Google's own search engine for site search that has [AdSense for search](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9879?hl=en).

> [Ads on dynamic content](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Dynamic)
>
> Publishers may not place ads on pages or sites where dynamic content (such as live chats, instant messaging, and/or auto-refreshing comments) is the primary focus.

### Ads are not allowed to be placed on exit pages

You are violating this policy by publishing ads on an interstitial created when a user leaves the site.

> [Misleading Placement for Ads on Thank You, Exit, or Error pages](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ads_on_non_content_pages)
>
> Publishers are not permitted to place ads on any non-content-based pages like thank you, error, or exit pages. These are pages that visitors see on a site before potentially leaving the domain, sometimes after performing a specific action on the site such as a purchase or download. Error pages can be 404 error pages informing the user that there is no content to be found on this page. Ads that are the main focus on these types of pages can confuse a visitor into thinking that the ads are actual content, so we ask that ads are not placed on such pages.

Comment: It's odd because I have seen other sites like Forbes and even the Harvard Business review do this exact thing.  With regards to the dynamic content, it appears that placing AdSense ads for dynamically-generated search results is valid - see *AdSense code for dynamically generated pages*: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2806011?hl=en

Comment: In following the Forbes format, we do have content on the interstitial, so it's not just an ad page, large letters indicating the *Advertisement* just above it, and a link to allow them to continue, but it is in fact an exit page.  Thus, placing it before the actual content page, then no interstitial on that page to go to the original content would be ok?

Comment: Adsense doesn't want ads to be triggered on unreviewed user entered content.  That is why they don't allow ads an search and chat.  You may be able to use other ad networks for exit pages, but it is specifically against the AdSense terms of service.   This hour long video goes into a lot of detail: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vaGXIl8qgMk

Comment: Great, thanks.  In your opinion, what are some recommended ad networks to make use of for these exit pages?

Comment: I only use AdSense myself, so I am unfamiliar with the policies of other networks.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller I think there might be a slight error in your answer. According to https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354757?hl=en if you have non-Google search results pages on your site, you're welcome to place Google ads on them.